# MUI select component warnings: No Label no label associated with a form field. How can I clean the warnings?

Tags: select, material-ui, components

I tried to use MUI select component. But I found it throws a lot of warnings. Even I directly open the MUI home page, I also see those warnings.
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/

[Warnings on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bFAd.png)

I tried it on both Chrome and Edge and got the same problem.

How can I clean the warnings? Is it the problem of my browser?

BTW, if I provided a name prop in the Select component, the first warning as following will be cleaned:
An form field element should have an id or name attribute.

The page already provided an id attribute but it does not work.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            name='demo-name'
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={age}
            label="Age"
            onChange={handleChange}
        >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Thanks,

I just want to clean the warnings from the web page.